# How to debug php code in remote server with phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I come from the .net world, where F5 on visual studio just triggers debug and hits the breakpoints easily.

I dont have a local dev server, but I do have a remote dev server and I already setup the environment in phpstorm and magicento. (so magento development)

I used this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReOzltfka9o

Can I debug remotely, lets say I upload a new php file, trigger the execution on the server, and then I want to hit a breakpoint locally?  How can I do that?

THanks

Comment: You're going to have to go old school dude; the good ol' days of `SFTP`, `var_dump();` and `die;` :)

Comment: omg php sucks then!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with Magento.

Comment: This has a lot to do with Magento. The Magento pros use PHP storm with magicento and if you want to reduce your time writing Magento code by 95% then this is how you do it. Unfortunately, I still have not gotten it to work yet myself.

Comment: > omg php sucks then!   
No Dude, You have been misinformed. Its pretty much possible to add breakpoint and debug in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote debugging is possible with PhpStorm.

First you have to install Xdebug on your remote server and allow remote debugging with `xdebug.remote_enable=On` in the xdebug.ini.

Then you have to configure the server and the path mapping in PhpStorm under Settings > PHP > Servers.

After this you can enable the listener (the little telephone icon) and open the project in the browser. PhpStorm should now recognize the connection and stop at the breakpoints.

Comment: Although this might not be possible with some Magento Extensions - for example we have a Varnish extension that exceeds 100 loop limit with eval, only when xdebug profiling is enabled.

Comment: @Thorsten I am confused by the myriad settings. With the listener on in PhpStorm, I can then load a page in my browser, with the XDebug browser plugin turned on (to automatically trigger the server's XDebug), and the server will send back debug info, right? But the debug port is 9000, right? I have not been able to get that info back in my XDebug. Do I have to forward port 9000 from my router to my current machine? Or do I open an SSH tunnel? Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: I found this link which confirms some of my thoughts about the debug port. Currently I am testing on a local virtual machine to see if I can get that working first. Then I will try remote. http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html